# How to tell if I'm in MacVim in .vimrc

Tags: mac-osx, vim, vimrc

In my .vimrc, I want to check if I'm in MacVim vs. regular vim so I can optionally set some MacVim-specific settings, which should not be applied to regular vim.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I just found one way to do it:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    " set macvim specific stuff
endif
```

Comment: `has("gui_running")` will get you support for both macvim and gvim so will make your .vimrc more portable.

Comment: I noticed this condition is true either if I run macvim in terminal or GUI app. I is a way to check wether macvim is running in terminal?

Comment: For MacVim it looks like `has("gui_macvim")` returns true if it is running as a GUI or on the commandline. However `has("gui_running")` only seems to return true if MacVim is running as a GUI.